# Matrix manipulation and value validation

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation

I'm having some difficulties to perform the manipulation of an array and its validation.

I have this json, inside it I have an array.

```
{
"joias": [
  {
    "id": 1000001924,
    "nome": null,
    "data": null,
    "versao": 3,
    "joia": "ouro",
    "pedra": "não tem",
    "tamanho": "2",

    "versoes": [
     {
        "id": 1000001924,
        "nome": null,
        "data": null,
        "versao": 2,
        "joia": null,
        "pedra": "não tem",
        "tamanho": "2"
     }, 
     {
        "id": 1000001924,
        "nome": null,
        "data": null,
        "versao": 1,
        "joia": null,
        "pedra": "não tem",
        "tamanho": "2"
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

I want this array to be transformed into small "objects": following example:

```
{
        "nome": null,
        "data": null,
        "versao": 2,
        "joia": null
     }, 
     {
        "nome": null,
        "data": null,
        "versao": 2,
        "pedra": "não tem"
     },
     {
        "nome": null,
        "data": null,
        "versao": 2,
        "tamanho": "2"
     }
```

today I did it this way:

```
const model = versoes.reduce((objeto, versoes) => {
  for (let key in versoes) {
    objeto.push({
      versoes: versoes.versao,
      data: versoes.registroLog,
      autor: versoes.usuarioLog.nome,
      [key]: versoes[key],
    });

    console.log(form.get(key).value)


    // this.campoForm = form.get(key).value
  }

  return objeto;
}, []);
```

but I don't know if this form is correct, because after it I need to validate the last version (in this case the 3) with the 2 version

To validate these versions, I need to compare the value of my new array with that of the form, but I don't know how to do that, if someone can help me, I'm very grateful.

```
 build(versoes: any, form: AbstractControl): void {

// Retornar somente os 4 dados necessários
const model = versoes.reduce((objeto, versoes) => {
  for (let key in versoes) {
    objeto.push({
      versoes: versoes.versao,
      data: versoes.registroLog,
      autor: versoes.usuarioLog.nome,
      [key]: versoes[key],
    });

    console.log(form.get(key).value)


    // this.campoForm = form.get(key).value
  }

  return objeto;
}, []);

// Ordenar versoes
const ordenarVersoes = model.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.versoes - b.versoes;
});
}
```

this is the method i created, it receives the json and the form.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste sample code rather than pasting screen shots so people and run the code themselves and see the output. You've also got an array inside an array. Is this intentional because I don't see how your code handles that at all.

Comment: of course, I edited the question